# socket.bind() vs socket.listen()

Tags: python, sockets

I've learned how to write a python server, and figured out that I have a hole in my knowledge.
Therefore, I would glad to know more about the differences between the commands `bind()`, `listen()` of the module called socket.

In addition, when I use `bind()` with a specific port as a parameter, Is the particular port being in use already, before using the `listen()` method?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a [tutorial](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html) which explains in detail:

> ... **bind()** is used to associate the socket with the server address.
>
> Calling **listen()** puts the socket into server mode, and accept() waits for an incoming connection.

`listen()` is what differentiates a server socket from a client.

---

Once `bind()` is called, the port is now reserved and cannot be used again until either the program ends or the `close()` method is called on the socket.

A test program that demonstrates this is as follows:

```
import socket
import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

when running two instances of this program at once, you can see that the one started last has the error:

[image: Error image]

Which proves that the port is reserved before `listen()` is ever called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! the tutorial really improved my understanding, but I didn't understand yet if when we bind a ip + port, the specific port is taken.

Comment: I updated the answer with more information about how bind() reserves the port